# Cast an element in Eigen Vector/Matrix to a primitive double type

Tags: c++, eigen

Basically how do i do this

```
Eigen::RowVectorXd param(2);
param << 1.0, 2.0;
double last_element = param.tail(1); // error: no suitable conversion...
```

I know i can use `.coeff()` however in my code some vectors are being resized, thus the size is unknown a priori

Comment: To fix the code, you could write `double last_element = param.tail(1)[0]`. This selects the first element of the vector returned by `tail()`, making it possible to assign the value to a double. Better solutions are given in the answer by @mattlangford.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Would something like this work:

```
    Eigen::RowVectorXd param(2);
    param << 1.0, 2.0;
    double last_element = param(param.size() - 1);
```

or even better, using the Eigen provided `last` value:

```
    double last_element = param(Eigen::last);
```